# Flutter PageView: displaying single row of data from mysql database in multiple screen

Tags: php, flutter

I want to display a single row of data from mysql database in multiple screen in flutter PageView. The following website contains json data of mysql database. https://telugu-signaler.000webhostapp.com/get_user.php. It contains 10 user data, for each user, it has for columns namely user_first_name, user_last_name, user_district and user_state. I want to display user_first_name and user_last_name in a single screen and after swipe right display user_district and user_state in another screen. So, for 10 user there will be 20 page swipe.

The following my code displaying all 4 fields of a user data in a single screen but I want the logic as described above. Please help me to solve this logical error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class GetUserData extends StatefulWidget {
  const GetUserData({super.key});

  @override
  State<GetUserData> createState() => _GetUserDataState();
}

class _GetUserDataState extends State<GetUserData> {
  late PageController pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<List> getUserData() async {
    String url = 'https://telugu-signaler.000webhostapp.com/get_user.php';
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: '');
    var allUserData = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    return allUserData;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Get User Data'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                future: getUserData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: PageView.builder(
                        controller: pageController,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          var userFirstName =
                              snapshot.data![index]['user_first_name'];
                          var userLastName =
                              snapshot.data![index]['user_last_name'];
                          var userDistrict =
                              snapshot.data![index]['user_district'];
                          var userState = snapshot.data![index]['user_state'];

                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 229, 229),
                                //// I want following two Text() in one screen/page
                                child: Text(
                                  '$index- First Name: $userFirstName',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 229, 229),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Last Name: $userLastName',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 50,
                              ),

                              //// and after swipe right, I want to display following two Text() in another screen/page
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                                child: Text(
                                  '$index- District: $userDistrict',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                                child: Text(
                                  'State: $userState',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to stop using the FutureBuilder for the api calls, as the FutureBuilder rebuilds it self and calls the future function on every changing state so it will make api call repeatedly, you can use bloc or cubit instead.

For now here is the solution:

you just need manipulate the index of the PageViewBuilder, make the PageView with double the length of the dataList. in the builder divide the index by 2 floor it and pass it to the dataList and and get the data, now if the page index is in even show the firstName and lastName otherwise show district and state accordingly.

here i'm using some dummy data in the future function.

you can refer the below code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Get User Data'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                future: getUserData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: PageView.builder(
                        controller: PageController(),
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length * 2,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          bool isEvenIndex = index % 2 == 0;
                          int i = (index / 2).floor();
                          String userFirstName =
                              snapshot.data![i]['user_first_name'];
                          String userLastName =
                              snapshot.data![i]['user_last_name'];
                          String userDistrict =
                              snapshot.data![i]['user_district'];
                          String userState = snapshot.data![i]['user_state'];

                          return Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                color: isEvenIndex
                                    ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 229, 229)
                                    : Colors.lightGreen,
                                child: Text(
                                  '${i + 1}. ${isEvenIndex ? 'First Name: $userFirstName' : 'District: $userDistrict'}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: isEvenIndex
                                    ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 229, 229)
                                    : Colors.lightGreen,
                                child: Text(
                                  isEvenIndex
                                      ? 'Last Name: $userLastName'
                                      : 'State: $userState',
                                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was looking for this solution for long time. It is working the way I was looking for.